# Create a OwnerId method

Tags: apex, trigger, global-methods

I want to create a OwnerId method which takes in an opportunity as input , stores all OwnerId's from that Opportunity in a list and returns that list. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static OwnerId initOwnerId(Opportunity newOwner){
    List OwnerId = new List();
    for(List OwnerId : newOwner){
        OwnerId.add(newOwner.OwnerId);
    }
    insert OwnerId;
    return OwnerId;
}
```

Is this wrong? I'm not confident that this is the right way to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As Thomas mentioned, there is only ever one Owner on a record. If you can share your requirement we might be able to help you come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are *alot* of things wrong with your approach, including:

- Any object only has one OwnerId.
- OwnerId is not a type that can be returned.
- A single Opportunity cannot be the collection in a for loop.
- OwnerId is not an object that can be inserted.

Here is one such method that provides the functionality you're looking for (in bulk), but I *HIGHLY* recommend you review the [Apex docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/) and work through tutorials, or you will be asking alot of unnecessary questions. Check out the [Apex workbook](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook) as one such source for tutorials.

```
public static Set<Id> getOwnerIds(List<Opportunity> opps) {
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Opportunity opp : opps) {
        ownerIds.add(opp.OwnerId);
    }
    // in case of non-inserted opportunities...
    ownerIds.remove(null);
    return ownerIds;
}
```

Comment: Good advice Thomas

Comment: Thanks, you're completely right. I made the mistake of thinking I'd need ownerId when what I actually need to create is a user method class. Sorry for the confusion, but thanks for the tutorials, I'm sure they'll be helpful